# c - alphabetical order of chars: different output when run vs. debugged?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gdb

Here's my problem: the following compilable code produces different results when simply run vs. debugged. I use NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 with gdb debugger on Windows 10 with Cygwin tools.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int exists(int* arr, int len, int i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (arr[j] == i) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int* alpha_order(char* source, int len) {
    int* pos = malloc(sizeof(int) * len);

    char c = SCHAR_MAX;
    int cpos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if ((c > *source) && (exists(pos, len, j) != 1)) {
                c = *source;
                cpos = j;
            }

            source++;
        }

        source -= len;
        c = SCHAR_MAX;

        pos[i] = cpos;
    }

    return pos;
}

int main(void) {

    char* str = "JACUZZI";
    int len = strlen(str);

    int* pos = alpha_order(str, len);

    printf("[%s]\n", str);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("[%c] : %d\n", str[pos[i]], (i + 1));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm expecting here is the following result, which I'm successfully able to obtain every time I debug the project (with a breakpoint e.g. on the line `pos[i] = cpos;`):

```
[JACUZZI]
[A] : 1
[C] : 2
[I] : 3
[J] : 4
[U] : 5
[Z] : 6
[Z] : 7
```

However, when I just run the project, this is the erroneous output that I get:

```
[JACUZZI]
[A] : 1
[C] : 2
[I] : 3
[U] : 4
[Z] : 5
[Z] : 6
[Z] : 7
```

I suspect there is an issue with memory management in my code. This is my first time trying out C and I'm more familiar with Java (which has garbage collection). So I'm having a very hard time realizing what the problem is, especially considering that debugging the project results in exactly what I want on every step.

The algorithm I wrote iterates over a string (`char*` array) to find the minimum value and stores the position into an `int*` array. The `int*` array is also used to check for positions that have already been taken into account. This is done over and over until a position for every character in the string is stored in the `int*` array.

The final output is the alphabetical order of the characters in the given string. I believe the time-complexity is O(n^3) and I realize that there may be more efficient ways to get the same result, however I want to point out I'm still getting used to C in general. Baby steps.

Solving this problem is useful as I approach multi-dimensional arrays (and pointers) in C. I prefer learning by coding, however I also have a book at hand. E.g. this algorithm can be applied in the implementation of a columnar transposition encoder/decoder. So if you can point out bad coding practices in my code, let me know. That said, I strongly value answers that help me find the issue that seems to escape the debugger and I'm at a point where I just don't know what to try next.

Thanks.

Comment: Why `char c = SCHAR_MAX;` instead of `char c = CHAR_MAX;`?

Comment: `exists(pos, len, j)` searches `pos[]` for length of `len`, yet not all elements are assigned  yet.

Comment: That's it! I created another variable `int k = 0;` to track the iteration within the two for-loops and is incremented every time the position is stored into `pos*`. The program works as intended, though is there any explanation why I wasn't able to find this problem with the debugger?

Comment: Also, you tell me! SCHAR_MAX vs. CHAR_MAX (vs. UCHAR_MAX). As I said, I'm just starting out. The upper range that CHAR_MAX covers is not needed and I don't see a problem. (Granted, I don't think I'll use/encounter negative sign chars in my code, but I'm not specifically coding with unsisigned chars in mind either.) Correct me if this thinking is wrong.

Comment: "The upper range that CHAR_MAX covers is not needed" --> how did you determine that?  By assuming code is using ASCII?  By assuming `SCHAR_MAX,  CHAR_MAX` have particular values?  The _reason_ for these defines are to reduce assumptions. In your case, "upper range that `CHAR_MAX` covers is not needed" is likely false as `"JACUZZI"` is likely in the _upper quartile_ of `char` on your compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here, as you've discovered within the depths of your comments, is that your program was using uninitialised values.

Your debugger would probably have zeroed your `malloc`'d memory, where-as when you compile for release/production that zeroing would be optimised away.

Another potential solution, aside from keeping track of the number of *assignments* you made and using that in place of `len` in `exists(pos, len, j)`, would have been to explicitly zero `pos` directly after allocation (e.g. `memset(pos, '\0', sizeof *pos * len)`), or use `calloc` as this performs the zeroing for you.

Comment: This explains the difference in behaviour. Thanks! I still have much to learn: I didn't even think of `malloc` not initializing memory block for me.